Why zero-overlap approximation is used for explaning the relation between the ΔE(AO) and the effectiveness of resulted MO?
In Atkins' physical chemistry 10e, page 424, eq 10D.8c, zero overlap approximation is used to obtain an expression for the energies for the molecular orbitals. I could not understand why zero overlap approximation is used. It looks that the orbital overlap causes the formation of molecular orbitals from atomic orbitals. If yes, why can one ignore orbital overlap to get energies ?  Thank you very much for your help !


You shouldn't copy pages like that.

There are several approximations made just to arrive at the equations shown. To simplify the interpretation of 10D.8a, the authors introduced one more: setting the mathematical expression for the overlap contribution to 0. This is done to illustrate the difference between the homonuclear case and a (very) heteronuclear case. In the former, overlap is the only factor, in the latter, orbital energies¹ dominate. Helpfully, the authors suggest a numerical exercise on the next page for the reader to convince themselves of the minor influence of overlap in this case.
So yes, to arrive at this model, you need orbital overlap. To more easily grasp the important bits, within one energy expression, one more simplification is made: set the overlap $S$ to zero.

¹ Caveat: orbital energies and spatial extent of an orbital and thus overlap with some other orbital are not independent. This can be neglected for the intended audience of this textbook.
